# How could I make this simple code more efficient?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to programming in general, and since I'm purely self taught, I lack some of the fundamentals of programming. This is some simple jQuery I wrote to make sure that the wrapper of a site stretches to the beginning of the footer, even if there isn't enough content:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var footerHeight = 147;
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var properHeight = windowHeight - footerHeight;
    $('#main').height(properHeight);
});
```

I define the height of the footer. Then I get the height of the viewport. Then I minus the height of the footer from the viewport. Then I apply that height to the `#main` element. I know I can use jQuery to get the height of the footer, but I had issues and it wasn't working right for some reason.

I have the code repeated just before, but outside of the `$('window').resize()` function, so that it runs once on on page load.

I feel like I could turn this into a function since it's repeated twice. Also, my main reason for asking here, is because if I resize the browser quickly for a couple seconds, my browser just eats up the CPU because of this code.

Apologies if this isn't the right site to ask.

Comment: Belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'll post there in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to keep this from eating your cpu while resizing would be to make this only happen at the end of the resize doing something like:

```
function afterResize()
{
    var footerHeight = 147;
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var properHeight = windowHeight - footerHeight;
    $('#main').height(properHeight);
}

var timeout = null;
$(window).resize(function() 
{
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){ afterResize(); }, 100);    
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RxRcQ/1/

Comment: I've implemented this into my js file and it seems to help. I can live with a small cpu usage spike since people don't resize their browser so violently anyway unless they're testing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could just programmatically trigger the `resize` event on the window, after binding the event handler:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    // your code here
}).resize();
```

That saves you duplicating the `// your code here` part outside of the function to do it before an actual `resize` event is triggered.

The CPU issue you've mentioned likely has less to do with the actual code inside your function (which is relatively trivial), and more to do with the number of `resize` events that are triggered. Taken from [the jQuery docs for `.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/):

> Code in a resize handler should never rely on the number of times the handler is called. Depending on implementation, resize events can be sent continuously as the resizing is in progress (the typical behavior in Internet Explorer and WebKit-based browsers such as Safari and Chrome), or only once at the end of the resize operation (the typical behavior in some other browsers such as Opera).

Comment: I didn't know I could manually trigger the resize event. Super useful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done is good as you need to definitely call it upon window.resize() event, as that causes the viewport to change.

As suggested by many, it is beneficial to manually trigger the resize event.

To enhance the algorithm, you could probably use less variables. Like below.

```
    var postResize;
    $(window).resize(function() {
            clearTimeout(postResize);
            postResize = setTimeout(function() {
                    var footerHeight = 147;
                    $("#main").height($(window).height() - footerHeight);
            }, 100);
    }).resize();
```

Above algorithm adds a performance enhancement: It doesn't do viewport calculation until the user stops resizing the window for 100ms. This makes the function call only once (instead of 400-500 calls) when you resize the window by 400-500 pixels (for example).

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger the resize event yourself.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var footerHeight = 147;
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var properHeight = windowHeight - footerHeight;
    $('#main').height(properHeight);
}).resize();
```

though depending on your content, you may want to wait until after window load to do it.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var footerHeight = 147;
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var properHeight = windowHeight - footerHeight;
    $('#main').height(properHeight);
}).on("load",function(){
    $(window).resize();
});
```